# Sybase SQL: Find last character in a string and replace it

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a string in the field `context`. The strings in this field are build in two versions. I need to append the string by following logic.

- Find last `“` in this string
- Replace this character `“` with following string: 123

Now I tried this without success

```
declare @pf varchar(10), @pos int, 
select @pflist = context,
       @pos = LEN(@pflist) - CHARINDEX('"',REVERSE(@pflist))    
UPDATE table SET CONTEXT = str_replace(convert(varchar(255),CONTEXT), ',
                 "'+ @pos +'"', '123’)
```

So basically I set the field with the string to a variable, tried to reverse that field, save the position in variable @pos and replace the string in that position with my string 123.

I get the message: `invalid column name CONTEXT`. So I guess this causes trouble `@pflist = context,`

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: I think context is your field so shouldn't your select should say select "@"pflist = context from table? if it returns multiple rows then you should say select "@"pflist = context from table where id=2 something on that front?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    declare @pf varchar(10), @pos int, 
    select @pflist = context, @pos = LEN(@pflist) - CHARINDEX('"',REVERSE(@pflist))

    UPDATE table SET CONTEXT = CONCAT(LEFT(CONTEXT, CHARINDEX('"',CONTEXT)-1), '123')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make such modification for all rows at the table - you could use next script:

```
select    
    Left(CONTEXT, LEN(CONTEXT) - CHARINDEX('"',REVERSE(CONTEXT))) + '123' + Right(CONTEXT, CHARINDEX('"',REVERSE(CONTEXT))-1)
from TABLE
```